# How to use systemJS to bundle up my unit testing scripts in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, systemjs

In my Angular 2 app directory, together with all the components, I have javascript unit test scripts. They `require()` different classes and angular2/core modules, however I cannot test with Karma, since require() isn't allowed in the browser. I am using SystemJS module bundler, but don't know how to approach making a bundle on them when I run the test.

My `karma.conf.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: '',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: [
          'app/**/*.spec-compiled.js'
        ],


        exclude: [
        ],

        preprocessors: {
        },

        reporters: ['progress'],

        port: 9876,

        colors: true,

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        autoWatch: true,

        browsers: ['Chrome'],


        singleRun: false,

        concurrency: Infinity
   })
}
```

Comment: just curious. why are you bundling something that will never be run in production? just do your "imports" and systemjs will load your modules on the fly (one at a time).

Comment: Em, in order to run my tests? SystemJS loads just the typescript/ES6 Angular 2 modules. I still can't get the unit tests to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation and I use a barrel to build the bundle.

My barrel is src/test/index.ts, it basically re-exports all tests:

```
export * from '../about/about.spec';
export * from './core/components/dropdown.spec';
export * from './core/models/session.spec';
export * from './core/models/user.spec';
export * from './core/models/version.spec';
export * from './core/services/simple-user-service.spec';
export * from './admin/simple-user-list.spec';
...
```

At that point, I bundle src/test/index.ts and it pulls automatically all the required dependencies.